# Display 9x9 BoardCell with android

Tags: android

I am trying to draw a board with 81 boardcell for 9x9 dimension board.

```
public abstract class BoardCell {
 private float x, y;
 public BoardCell( float x, float y ) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
 }

 public abstract void drawBoardCell( Canvas canvas, float x, float y, float width, Paint paint );
}
```

Then I have other subclass Board extends and implement all the abstract method from BoardCell.

My question is can I do something like:

```
Class Game extends View {
  BoardCell[][] myBoard;
  for( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ ) {
    for( int j = 0; j < 9; j++ ) {
      myBoard[i][j] = new Board( x, y );
      myBoard.drawBoardCell( canvas, x, y, width, paint );
    }
  }
}
```

My code works with BoardCell myBoard but not with 2D array of BoardCell :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the index of the newest board you've just made. Change

```
myBoard.drawBoardCell( canvas, x, y, width, paint );
```

to

```
myBoard[i][j].drawBoardCell( canvas, x, y, width, paint );
```

You also need to wrap your code in a method and instantiate your array. If you're not sure how this works, read up on some Java tutorials, there are many of them out there.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you need to instantiate the array first. You simply define myBoard.

```
BoardCell[][] myBoard = new BoardCell [9][9];
```